# Calculate probability within a loop - Python3

Tags: python, math, formula, probability, spotify

Good evening!
I have just picked up Python last month and I am having a lot of fun with it!

I am writing my first program ever in order to determine what are the probability of 2 songs of a same album playing back to back in a Spotify shuffled playlist: Sbotify! I have the use input sorted out but I cannot find a way to apply the probability formula for a value.

The formula used will be to multiply the probabilities of each separate event by one another as described in [this article](https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Probability) *(method 2-3)*. I need to multiply an imputed value int() by itself -1 on repeat until this value reaches 0 and then do the same thing for another value and so on and so forth.

I have tried:

- for loops
- Map() function
- Range() *to bypass the int cannot be integrate error*

But nothing seem to work. I've looked for an answer for hours and I cannot seem to find anything that fits my purpose. Any link, resource, or knowledge is much welcomed!

Here is my code,

```
import math
import statistics

print("\nHey user! Sbotify has for purpose to tell you the probability of \n
playing a song of the same album in a shuffled Spotify playlist. \n\n")
total_songs = int(input("\nEnter the total of your songs:"))

lst = []
num = int(input('Enter a number of albums: '))
for n in range(num):
    numbers = int(input('Enter number of song for each album: '))
    lst.append(numbers)
print("Sum of songs belonging to an album is :", sum(lst))
print(lst)

print("\nLet's find out the songs that don't belong to any album. This will be handy later:")

solo_songs = total_songs - sum(lst)
print(int(solo_songs))

# I'm afraid we need to use... **MATH**

print("Nice! Now we need to find out the probabilities of 2 songs of the same album playing back to back in shuffle mode")

#Each album needs to be considered 1 entity and to that, the solo_songs value needs to be multiplied by itself -1 until 0
#to respect the probability formula
```

let me know if anything is correct, over complicated or to be redone completely!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi! Interesting problem. I'd like to point out that spotify's "shuffle" option is **not** a uniform shuffle. At some point people were complaining that this "back-to-back" phenomenon happened too often. So spotify "derandomized" their shuffle algorithm, and instead pseudo-shuffles the list in a way that distributes songs from a same album over the list to avoid adjacent songs from the same album. So the probability using spotify's algorithm instead of a uniform random shuffle is close to 0.

Comment: Assuming a truly uniform shuffle, it looks like your problem is more a math problem than a programming problem. If you know the formula, then implementing it in python with `for`-loops will probably be easy. But finding out the formula is not obvious.

Comment: If you're just looking for "how to compute `n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 3 * 2 * 1` given an integer `n`", this is called the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of `n` and in python you can get it without any effort as `from math import factorial`. But if you want to code it yourself, here is one way: `def factorial(n): f = 1; for x in range(2, n+1): f *= x; return f`

Comment: Hey @Stef Thank you so very much for your help, factorial is probably what I indeed need.

Comment: I know that Spotify is using and algorithm, but for the sake of this exercise I'll be considering that it is based on a true random shuffle. It's good practice and I'm learning a ton through this little project!

Comment: Or alternatively `from math import prod; def factorial(n): return prod(range(2,n+1))`. Or alternatively `from functools import reduce; from operator import mul; def factorial(n): return reduce(mul, range(2, n+1), 1)`

Comment: If you do end up with a code that correctly calculates the desired probability, I suggest posting that code in a question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com . There are a lot of small details in your code that are not wrong but could be improved. (Read the guidelines of codereview first - it's very different from stackoverflow. In particular they only accept code that already works correctly.)

Comment: Thank you Stef! I'll be running my code through many trials to ensure that it is working fully before to submit it to codereview after making sure it fits their guidelines.